# recursive loop to get values from php array

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, recursion, foreach

I search a Solution to get all values from `[BrowseNodeId]` and `[Name]` from all `[Ancestors]` in a new array called categories. I think it must be a recursive loop, but how?

```
Array (
    [BrowseNodeId] => 343505011
    [Name] => Kinderzimmer
    [Ancestors] => Array (
        [BrowseNode] => Array (
            [BrowseNodeId] => 3517801
            [Name] => MÃ¶bel
            [Ancestors] => Array (
                [BrowseNode] => Array (
                    [BrowseNodeId] => 3312261
                    [Name] => MÃ¶bel & Wohnaccessoires
                    [Ancestors] => Array (
                        [BrowseNode] => Array (
                            [BrowseNodeId] => 3169011
                            [Name] => Kategorien
                            [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                            [Ancestors] => Array (
                                [BrowseNode] => Array (
                                    [BrowseNodeId] => 3167641
                                    [Name] => KÃ¼che & Haushalt
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you include what you have tried and what did/din't work as expected?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function getAllInfo($inputArray, $outputArray = array()) {
    $outputArray[] = array(
        'BrowseNodeId' => $inputArray['BrowseNodeId'],
        'Name' => $inputArray['Name']
    );
    if(isset($inputArray['Ancestors']['BrowseNode'])) {     
        return getAllInfo($inputArray['Ancestors']['BrowseNode'], $outputArray);
    }
    return $outputArray;    
}
```

See it in action here (with the test array you provided): http://3v4l.org/jd7hY